# Autocomplete using php, jquery, mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am using this source code : http://www.htmlblog.us/jquery-autocomplete in my project but I am not able to fetch the result when I type in the autocomplete textbox.

Where am I going wrong ?

I use the following code

**Javascript :** (I use a separate file for this javascript and checked if this calls using alert and I am able to generate alert messages at runtime.)

```
jQuery(document).ready
 (
    function()
        {
                $('#CourseId').autocomplete( { url:'AutoComplete_Courses.php', minLength:2 } );                
        }
 );
```

**Php:**

```
<?php

echo('Your password must be at least 8 characters long');
if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
    exit;

$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('mydatabase');

$rs = mysql_query('select courseid, coursename, creditpoints from coursedetails where coursename like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" order by coursename asc limit 0,10', $dblink);

$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['courseid'] .', '. $row['coursename'] .' '. $row['creditpoints'] ,
            'value' => $row['courseid']
        );
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

Comment: And the question is (other than : "what's wrong") ?

Comment: I suggest if you have a problem following the blog-post, discuss it with the author there.

Comment: What happens if you open `http://domain/AutoComplete_Courses.php?term=test`?

Comment: I don't get any error but when I type first 2 (because minLength:2) letters inside my autocomplete textbox, I see a cursor rotating and nothing happens, it just keeps on rotating.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: yes I initially tried with PDO and since it was not working I used the similar code used by the author

Comment: ok. 

Instead of 
$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('mydatabase');


I put 
include 'Config.php'; [Inside Config file : $dblink = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=UTF-8', 'root', '');] 


But, $dblink is null, is there any other way or am Ii doing any wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for the AutoComplete plugin. It looks like you used the wrong object property.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

As you can see, there is no '**url**' property, use '**source**' instead.

Change this line:

`$('#CourseId').autocomplete( { url:'AutoComplete_Courses.php', minLength:2 } );`

to

`$('#CourseId').autocomplete( { source:'AutoComplete_Courses.php', minLength:2 } );`

Additionally, whenever I'm having trouble with data coming from a database, I typically wrap the variable in PHP's built-in output function var_dump() to see how PHP formatted the data.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: I initially tried with source but since it was not working I tried with url !

Comment: Why change it to 'url?' That is not a property in the documentation. At least change it back.

Comment: ok, is it not possible to include a php file in the above code for data connection. Include 'Config.php'; (which has PDO connection)

Comment: ok. 

Instead of 
$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('mydatabase');


I put 
include 'Config.php'; [Inside Config file : $dblink = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=UTF-8', 'root', '');] 


But, $dblink is null, is there any other way or am Ii doing any wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not gonna work if you break the expected JSON result by prefixing random text with your unconditional `echo()` output.

Remove that:

```
echo('Your password must be at least 8 characters long');
```

Else the autocomplete plugin will receive

```
garbage text here [{"json":"won't be readable"},...]
```

Comment: I removed "echo('Your password must be at least 8 characters long');" but it is not fetching any records.

Comment: Do some basic debugging as suggested by @dfsq

Comment: how do I check the  value of $rs is able to fetch records ?